# Mistake in SQL syntax.. (bindValue?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create an update query and I am looping in some set stuff to a var called $str and I cant seem to get it to work.

```
       if (is_numeric($id)) {
           if (!empty($values) && !empty($table_name)) {
               $str = '';
               $sql = "UPDATE `$table_name` SET :update_values WHERE `$column_name` = :id";

               // Its one because we dont use ID like that
               $i = 1;

               foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                   if ($key != $column_name) {
                       // Exclude the last one from having a comma at the end
                       if ($i == count($values) - 1) {
                           $str .= "$key='" . $value . "'";
                       } else {
                           $str .= "$key='" . $value . "', ";
                           $i++;
                       }
                   }
               }
               $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
               $query->bindValue('update_values', $str, PDO::PARAM_STR);
               $query->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
               $query->execute();
               return true;  
           } else {
               return false;
           }
       } else{
           return false;
       }
   }
```

Output:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''note_name=\'yeet\', note_date=\'2020-02-20\',
>   note_desc=\'asdasdasdasdadsasdads' at line 1

Am I making any obvious mistakes?

Also for the life of me I don't know what the backslashes in front of the values mean.

Comment: You cannot just bind a string for all of the SET values like you are trying to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, *identifiers* cannot be provided as *values*.

References to columns must appear in the text of the SQL statement, they cannot be provided through bind parameters. This holds true for table names, column names, function names.

There is no workaround; this is a by-design restriction. There's several reasons for this. One of the most straightforward reasons is understanding how a SQL statement gets prepared, the information that is needed to come up with an execution plan, the tables and columns have to be known at *prepare* time (for the semantic check and privilege check. The actual *values* can be deferred to execution time.

Bind placeholders are for providing *values*, not *identifiers*.

With the code given, what MySQL is seeing something along the lines of

```
 UPDATE `mytable` SET 'a string value' WHERE `id_col` = 42
```

And MySQL is balking at the `'a string value'`.

---

We can (and should) use bind parameters for values.

We could dynamically generate SQL text that looks like this:

```
    UPDATE `mytable`
       SET `col_one` = :val1
         , `col_two` = :val2
     WHERE `id_col` = :id
```

and after the SQL text is prepared into statement, we can bind values:

```
         $sth->bindValue(':val1', $value_one , PDO::PARAM_STR );
         $sth->bindValue(':val2', $value_two , PDO::PARAM_STR );
         $sth->bindValue(':id'  , $id        , PDO::PARAM_INT );
```

and then execute

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for clearing that up for me. Many thanks :)